# UPS with bad battery - okay to keep computing a while?

Tags: ups

My APC ES 350 UPC is beeping continuously, with an LED alternating red/green.  Nothing happened recently, just normal everyday functioning.   According to a quick web search, this beep and blinking means the battery is worn out and should be replaced.  I assume the computer is running of AC power passing through the UPC.

Is is ok to continue using the computer in this situation?

The AC power itself is good, and I expect no dropouts.  The beep is annoying, but more annoying would be having to shut down halfway through a massive computation taking several days, and restart all the software I have chugging away on things not designed to be restarted.  Can I just keep running until this stuff is done, then shut down? Any harm in doing that?

Comment: A few months ago my UPS would randomly shutdown: no output to any plug and without giving any warning even though the AC line was good.  Replacing the sealed 4-year-old battery cured that problem.  Don't wait for for the UPS battery to deteriorate unless you can recover from power failures.

Comment: So far, so good.  The UPS continues to provide power from AC.  I've had to muffle the annoying beep w/o causing overheating. One brief power blink-out and the several-day calculation is dead, but that's unlikely. Oops, I just jinxed myself by saying that.

Answer (score 1):

No, there shouldn't be a problem with that. But a power outage greater than several seconds will probably result in the computer shutting down, so you will want to replace the battery promptly.

Answer (score 0):

Batteries need to be replaced every 2-3 years on Battery backup surge protectors.

Depending on where you live, the frequency of surges is a factor on whether you should replace the battery in a timely manner.

You being in California, and we haven't seen rain in quite a while, a hot sunny area year around it's not as big of a deal to replace it right away.